# How to prefix remote topics in a multimaster setup with rocon?

Tags: ros, rocon, multimaster, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am experimenting with a multimaster setup. A central server S and two robots A and B. Currently I am using rocon.
When I flip a connection from A to S eg. /talker this will appear on S as /talker. Is there a way I missed to prefix this topic on S with /A resulting in /A/talker. This would allow to flip the same topic from B as well as this would result in /B/talker without prefixing all topics on B itself.
In the best case this could be behavior would be configurable at the gateway. The gateway has the knowledge where the request comes from and could prefix incoming requests without having the source knowing about the prefix.
Have a nice weekend.
Hannes

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253155/how-to-prefix-remote-topics-in-a-multimaster-setup-with-rocon?/) by [anonymous4756](https://answers.ros.org/users/4756/anonymous4756/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-01-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The usual method is to run each robot in its own namespace.

See: http://nootrix.com/software/ros-namespaces/

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2017-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous4756](https://answers.ros.org/users/4756/anonymous4756/) on 2017-02-01**:
Thanks for pointing to this link

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2018-01-04**:
The answer is correct:  namespacing each system is almost always a good idea, and I'd prefer to see the ROS tutorials using namespacing throughout.

`master_sync.py` in dpirozzo's Bitbucket `multimaster` is easily changed to advertise topics with prefixes. Uses foreign_relay and the ROS Master API.